# The use of argparser instead of the OptParser in Django >= 1.8

Tags: python, django

I recently trying to learn about argparse in python, this gave me  a hint on how programs like the Django framework and python itself give helpful Tracebacks for helping trace errors in a typical developers life :). I read about argparse in a few places to find out more and when I came across Django that changed from OptParser to argparser. What I know is argparser is just used for ***The program defines what arguments it requires, and argparse will figure out how to parse those out of sys.argv. The argparse module also automatically generates help and usage messages and issues errors when users give the program invalid arguments.***

My question is what does a command line parser like `OptParser` lack or what is better in argparse that made a huge framework Django change a cmd parser

Answer (score 1):

> *Deprecated since version 3.2:* The `optparse` module is deprecated and will not be developed further; development will continue with the `argparse` module.

[source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/optparse.html)